# TinyMCE Expands vertically

Tags: javascript, php, html, tinymce

last night I applied a new style on my webpage but my **TinyMCE  textarea editor** expanded *too much* .. i dont know where is the error I checked the new styling code and there were no conflict because i didnt put any style for . 
I tried to delete single styling block at a time to check if there was a conflict but nothing worked.

this is the image of the expanded editor!
  
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4bqZ.png

[image]

Regards,

Comment: Without seeing your complete code in action it will be hard to suggest anything. Perhaps you could use CodePen or JS Fiddle to make a fully functional page that shows this issue? stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: a CSS style is what made the TinyMCE expands >> I tried to put it out of a class and it was fine